# why am I getting output as none? and not the images in the code below

Tags: python, opencv

```
image_path=r'D:\\data\\Coding_round_images'

def loadImages(path):
    image_files = sorted(os.listdir(path))
    images=[]
    for i in image_files:
        images.append(i)
    return images

file=loadImages(image_path)
print(file)

images=[]                                             
for f in file:
    images.append(cv2.imread(f,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED))
    
print(images)
```

Comment: Where specifically are you getting `None`?

Comment: when i print  images i.e. the last line

Comment: you should use pdb to debug this. look up pdb cheatsheet

Comment: It isn't possible for the last `print` to print out `None`. It doesn't look like any of the `print`s here are capable of printing out `None`. Please double check your output.

Comment: when I run print(file) .It shows an output like this:
['lemon1.jpg', 'lemon2.jpg', 'lemon3.jpg', 'lemon4-586.jpg', 'lemon5.jpg', 'lemon6.jpg', 'lemon7.jpg', 'lemons1.jpeg'] 
but when I run the last print(images) I get an output like this:
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are executing the code in the same folder of the images

```
└── data
    └── Coding_round_images
        ├── lemon1.jpg
        ├── lemon2.jpg
        ├── lemon3.jpg
        └── load_lemons.py
```

Or, if it's not the same, add a prefix in the `cv2.imread` command with the image's path.

```
...
...
for f in file:
    images.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_path,f),cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED))
```

Because [cv2.imread](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html) doesn't return any error indication if the path or image does not exist.

> Even if the image path is wrong, it won’t throw any error, but print img will give you None

```
In [135]: x = cv2.imread("NON_EXISTING_IMAGE")
In [136]: type(x)
Out[136]: NoneType
```

Comment: Thank you so much @nn1colas.m  for the help. It worked.
I have 1 more question that why do I have to add the image path when already I have already uploaded the image using loadImages function above?

Comment: `os.listdir` only returns a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path, not the full path used as parameter to the command itself, then you try to use `cv2.imread` later you only have the file name.